# Получить значение сахара в крови из приложения Health IOS,Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Вот код программы

```
var ans : Double = 0.0

let sampleTypeBlood=HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodGlucose)
                self.readMostRecentSample(sampleTypeBlood!, completion: { (mostRecentBlood, error) -> Void in

                    if( error != nil )
                    {
                        print("Error reading weight from HealthKit Store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        return;
                    }
                    var blood: HKQuantitySample
                    blood = (mostRecentBlood as? HKQuantitySample)!;
                    ans = blood.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.moleUnitWithMolarMass(HKUnitMolarMassBloodGlucose)) // с этой строчкой возникают проблемы  
                    self.txtBox.text = String(ans)
```

Comment: спасибо, воспользуюсь

Comment: а что не работает то?